# Understanding when to use inheritance to allow one class to use instances of another

Tags: objective-c, oop, inheritance, composition

When creating classes, is there a rule for when to use inheritance and when to import a new class, without inheritance, into another?

Here’s an example:

I make a class called `Person`, and then create lots of `Person` objects.

I then create a child class called `House`. Using inheritance and properties, all my `Person` objects can now have a `House`.

I then create a child class called `Car` so all my `Person` objects now have `House`s and `Car`s.

and so on… and so on….

I now have this sequence of classes:

NSObject < Person < House < Car < new Class < another new Class, etc.

With the above scenario, my logic (I'm an Objective-C beginner) tells me I have two different ways of producing the same outcome:

1. As explained above, or
2. Create each class without inheritance and then import it into `Person` as an ivar – for example, an instance of `House` now becomes a type, and that is then imported into a `Person` object using properties.

Please excuse my lack of terminology and understanding.  If required, I can upload a code example but it’s more of a general question on when and when not to use inheritance.

Comment: Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49002/prefer-composition-over-inheritance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question is not specific to Objective-C: the guideline for when to use inheritance is the same for all object-oriented languages, and it is based on *substitutability*, summarized by the [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle):

> if S is a subtype of T, then objects of type T may be replaced with objects of type S

In other words, use inheritance only when you can say "{derived} *is a* {base}>"; when you model a "{owner} *has a* {something}", use composition

- Student *is a* Person -- Inheritance
- Car *is a* vehicle -- Inheritance
- Person *has a* House -- Composition (ivar or property)
- Car *has a(n)* Engine -- Composition (ivar or property)

Comment: thank you very much that really answers my question and gives me a rule to stick to. It currently seems easier just to keep inheriting every class but as I learn more about Obj-C I'm sure it will make more sence.